# Multiple IActor interfaces

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a need for an `Actor` to implement multiple interfaces. Is this possible?

Currently, when I attempt to have the `Actor` type implement an interface that derives from another interface which derives from `IActor`, I get a message that it implements multiple interfaces, and `ActorServiceAttribute` needs to be used to distinguish. Adding `ActorServiceAttribute` does not remove the error message.

[EDIT]

I believe I solved this problem. The errors are confusing. You need to directly implement BOTH interfaces on the Actor type. The build-time discover does not seem to enumerate through the interface hierarchy to find `IActor`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting the issue. Can you provide information on your interface hierarchy. Adding the ActorServiceAttribute on the actor with the valid service name should have resolved the error. By default the actor services are named using the actor interfaces. In this case since there are two different actor interfaces (IBaseActor, IDerivedActor) that are implemented by the actor, runtime cannot determine the naming for the actor service. This is because on the client side, one can create ActorProxy or ActorProxy.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce it EXACTLY as I described above. `ActorServiceAttribute` is fixing it. That said, `Actor1` : `IActorSub` : `IActorBase` : `IActor` produces the error.

I think the error makes sense now. Even though there's an inheritance chain here, both interfaces `IActorSub` and `IActorBase`, eventually implement `IActor`.